# Asp.Net core 2 Web Api running as service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to run a asp.net core 2 web api as a windows service. I'm targeting .Net 4.6.1 Framework. I created a basic project from visual studio template, by not changing anything except Program.cs Main method to

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

            var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.RunAsService();
        }
```

When I try to start my windows service, I get the foloowing error in event viewer

```
Version du Framework : v4.0.30319
Description : le processus a été arrêté en raison d'une exception non gérée.
Informations sur l'exception : System.TypeLoadException
Pile :
   à Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(System.AggregateException ByRef)
   à Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   à deploy.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Any clue what's happening here ? I deployed numerous web api as web service without problems in the past, but they all were built on asp.net core 1.0.

UPDATE

Ends up that hosting machine didn't have .Net Framework 4.6.1 installed (duh!).

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported yet as it is stated [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1173)

Comment: I found the complete "recipe" for asp.net core 2.0 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: that link states that .Net Framework 4.6.1 Template is needed "When creating a project in Visual Studio, use the ASP.NET Core Application (.NET Framework) template"

Comment: If this answer gave you enough information please consider to mark it as solution.